# Show that there is no differentiable function $f :\Bbb R \to\Bbb R$ such that $f(0) = 1$ and $f'(x) ≥ (f(x))^2\space\forall x\in\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, problem-solving

> Show that there is no differentiable function $f :\Bbb R \to\Bbb R$ such that $f(0) = 1$ and $f'(x) ≥ (f(x))^2\space\forall x\in\Bbb R$.

My attempt:

Suppose there is a differentiable function such that the above statement holds true.

Then, as the function is differentiable so it will satisfy the mean value theorem.
$$f(x)-f(0)=f'(c)(x-0),x>0,c \in (0,x)$$

$$f(x)-1=f'(c)x$$
$$f(x)-1 \ge (f(c))^2 x$$
$$f(x)-(f(c))^2 x -1 \ge 0$$

If we let $h(x) = f(x)-(f(c))^2.x-1$ then $h'(x) \ge 0$ then $f'(x)-(f(c))^2 \ge 0$ . How do I proceed after this and obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Now there is an error in your last step. You cannot factor out $f(x)$ from $f(c)^2$.

Comment: is the contradiction due to the fact that $f(x) \ge f(c)^2.x+1$ which makes it unbounded?

Comment: You might consider instead the inequality $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}\ge 1$$ wherever $f(x)\ne 0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin can you answer what is the intuition behind such a process because the first thing that came to my mind is that  to use mean value theorem

Comment: In general, integration is more powerful than MVT. Differential inequalities show up a lot in analysis and applications.

Comment: An almost identical question is [Is there differentiable $f: {\mathbb R}_+ \to {\mathbb R}_+$ such that $f'(x) > f(x)^2$ for all $x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1131027/42969).

Answer (score 7):

Consider the function $g(x) = x+\frac{1}{f(x)}$.

Note $g'(x)= 1-\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)} \leq 0$. Hence $g(x)$ is a non-increasing function.

But $f'(x) \geq f^2(x) \geq 0$ implies $f(x)$ is non-decreasing function.

Since, $f(0) = 1$ implies $f(x) \geq 1 \geq 0$ (as $f$ is non-decreasing$).

Hence $g(100) \geq 100 $ but $g(x)$ is a non-increasing function implies $g(100) \leq f(0) = 1$. This a contradiction.

Comment: Why did you consider $g(x)$ is this a natural process to assume such functions in thses types of sums?

Comment: I really like your method

Answer (score 2):

We may assume $f$ never vanishes for $x>0$. Because if there exists a point $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$, then by the mean-value theorem, one has a point $c\in (0,x_0)$ such that \begin{align*}
 f(x_0)-f(0) = f’(c)x_0\Rightarrow -1 \ge (f(c))^2 x_0 \ge 0
\end{align*}
which is not possible. So assume $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x>0$. Now, if $f’(x) \ge (f(x))^2$ is true, then one has
\begin{align*}
\frac{f’(x)}{f(x))^2} \ge 1 & \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{f(x) }\ge x + c 
\end{align*}
for some constant $c$. But for large enough $x>0$, we have $f(x) < 0$.

Since $f(0)=1 >0$, then by the intermediate value theorem, we must have $f(x’)=0$ for some $x’>0$. But we already assumed $f$ never vanishes.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am not getting the integration part can you help me out

Comment: What is $\int du/u^2$?

Comment: $\frac{-1}{u}$.

Comment: @ThirstforMaths You can try playing around with polynomials first say $f(x) = x^2$. And you see that at some point (eventually), the value of $f(x)^2$ will be larger than that of $f'(x)$.

Comment: I would recommend a rewrite here. First, integrate $$f'(t)/f(t)^2 \ge 1$$ from $0$ to $x$ to obtain $$1-\frac1{f(x)} \ge x, \quad\text{i.e.,}\quad f(x)\ge \frac1{1-x}.$$ So this tells us that as $x\to 1^-$, $f(x)\to\infty$.